# How could we grow plants on mars?

Tags: mars, plants

I was wondering there are ways to grow plants on the planet Mars and what would be needed to help them grow etc.

I know some key factors would be full spectrum bulbs and violet blue lights but there surely are some more stuff needed.

Comment: This is a super-broad question - can you narrow it down to a specific aspect that you'd like to focus on, maybe like "What are the challenges of growing plants in Martian soil", or "What are the challenges related to seasonality", et al.

Comment: It seems like you're reaching for something a bit more nuanced than the question Chris linked, but in the absense of any more detail your question will be closed as a duplicate. Perhaps you might be better off asking about "_what is the best way to grow food plants for a martian colony_", or similar. IMHO, the answer is probably something like [aeroponics](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=aeroponics), rather than faffing around with weird toxic clay.

Answer (score 4):

This question is rather broad so I will give a broad answer.

Plants on Mars will require similar things to plants growing on Earth. All of these things:

1. Sufficient Light
2. Appropriate dark periods*
3. Warmth
4. Water
5. Nutrients
6. Sufficient atmospheric pressure
7. An atmosphere containing carbon dioxide
8. Absence of toxic conditions such as high levels of radiation or chemical poisons

*some plants can live in continuous light some can’t. No plants will tolerate very long dark periods

1 and 2 would be available in low latitude and equatorial areas of Mars through a window, although low light levels during sandstorms might require auxiliary lighting.
3 Would require an energy source and heaters
4 Would also require an energy source and harvesting of ice (available locally in many areas on Mars)
5 Nutrients are almost certainly available on Mars, but will need to be brought from Earth initially due to uncertain distribution, purity/contamination and the complexity of refining on Mars.
6 and 7 would require an energy source, a compressor a dust filter and a pressure vessel.
8 would require that the plants are contained from the Martian environment due to the presence of perchlorate in the regolith which is toxic to plants. Radiation levels on Mars are much higher than on Earth but not sufficiently high to cause a significant problem for plant growth

In short plants will be grown on Mars, but will need to be isolated from the Martian environment in a pressure vessel and provided with the above. They will not be able to grow on the surface unprotected.

Comment: Actually, you just need two things: 1. A resourceful botanist, and 2. A lucky supply of Thanksgiving potatoes.

Comment: :o) mind you it didn't end that well for the veg IIRC